# Выпадение подменю вверх

Tags: html, css

Тренируюсь делать выпадающее меню. В хедере получилось, теперь скопировал тоже меню в футер. Удалось сделать, чтобы меню выпадало вверх, а вот чтобы и подменю выпадало вверх как и основное

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- не получается. Наводим на products- дропнулось вверх. Наводим на desctop- идет вниз.

```css
/*-----------------cammon start------------------*/

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #faf0e6;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.bc {
  background-color: #f4a460;
}

.container {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

a,
span {
  display: inline-flex;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*-----------------cammon end------------------*/


/*----------------header menu start------------------*/

.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.logo {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.logo>img {
  width: 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #0096d6;
}

.menu>li+li {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.menu li {
  position: relative;
}

.menu li:hover>a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.menu a {
  padding: 10px 25px;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #0096d6;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.drop-menu {
  padding-top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.drop-menu .drop-menu {
  padding-top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 10px;
  left: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.drop-menu>li+li {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.menu li:hover>.drop-menu {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}


/*----------------header menu end------------------*/


/*----------------footer menu start------------------*/

.fr {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: initial;
  bottom: 100%;
}


/*----------------footer menu end------------------*/
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="nav">
      <a href="index.html" class="logo">
        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="" />
      </a>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Products</a>
          <ul class="drop-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Laptops</a></li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Desktop</a>
              <ul class="drop-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Gaming</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Business</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Mac</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="#">Computer parts</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <!--   <div class="header-left bc">
          <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="header-right bc">
          <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="header-bottom bc">
          <p></p>
        </div>-->
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar-left bc">
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-middle bc">
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-left bc">
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-first bc">
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-second bc">
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <!--<div class="footer-first bc">
              <p></p>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-second bc">
              <p>27</p>
            </div>-->
        <nav class="nav">
          <a href="index.html" class="logo">
            <img src="img/logo.png" alt="" />
          </a>
          <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Products</a>
              <ul class="drop-menu fr ">
                <li><a href="#">Laptops</a></li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Desktop</a>
                  <ul class="drop-menu l2">
                    <li><a href="#">Gaming</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Business</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Mac</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>

                <li><a href="#">Computer parts</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Также необходимо задать

```
.fr .drop-menu {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Пример

```css
/*-----------------cammon start------------------*/

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li{
  list-style: none;
}

body {
  background-color: #faf0e6;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.bc {
  background-color: #f4a460;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

a,
span {
  display: inline-flex;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*-----------------cammon end------------------*/


/*----------------header menu start------------------*/

.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.logo {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.logo>img {
  width: 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #0096d6;
}

.menu>li+li {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.menu li {
  position: relative;
}

.menu li:hover>a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.menu a {
  padding: 10px 25px;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #0096d6;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.drop-menu {
  padding-top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.drop-menu .drop-menu {
  padding-top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 10px;
  left: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.drop-menu>li+li {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.menu li:hover>.drop-menu {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}


/*----------------header menu end------------------*/


/*----------------footer menu start------------------*/

.footer{
  margin-top: 200px;
}

.fr {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: initial;
  bottom: 100%;
}

.fr .drop-menu {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
}
/*----------------footer menu end------------------*/
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="nav">
      <a href="index.html" class="logo">
        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="" />
      </a>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Products</a>
          <ul class="drop-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Laptops</a></li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Desktop</a>
              <ul class="drop-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Gaming</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Business</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Mac</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="#">Computer parts</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <!--   <div class="header-left bc">
          <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="header-right bc">
          <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="header-bottom bc">
          <p></p>
        </div>-->
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar-left bc">
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-middle bc">
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-left bc">
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-first bc">
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-second bc">
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <!--<div class="footer-first bc">
              <p></p>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-second bc">
              <p>27</p>
            </div>-->
        <nav class="nav">
          <a href="index.html" class="logo">
            <img src="img/logo.png" alt="" />
          </a>
          <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Products</a>
              <ul class="drop-menu fr ">
                <li><a href="#">Laptops</a></li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Desktop</a>
                  <ul class="drop-menu l2">
                    <li><a href="#">Gaming</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Business</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Mac</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>

                <li><a href="#">Computer parts</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```